# Magento - Show Custom Product Attribute on My Account Order Information Page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Creating attribute in admin and assigning them to products, they can be seen on cart page as shown in below page

[Cart Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za3zM.png)

I have already added code in `config.xml` as shown

```
<sales>
         <quote>
            <item>
            <product_attributes>
                <my_custom_product_attribute/>
            </product_attributes>
            </item>
         </quote>
</sales>
```

After placing order, how do I show the same attribute on Order Information Page under Customer's My Order page.

[Order Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJLK0.png)

Tried below in config.xml, but I need to show the custom prod attributes in Order Info, Invoice and Refund pages in Customer as well as Admin section

```
<global>
    ...
    <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote>
            <your_special_attribute>
                <to_order>*</to_order>
            </your_special_attribute>
        </sales_convert_quote>
    </fieldsets>
    ...
    </global>
```

Answer (score 0):

On orders.phtml file get product sku from order oject and get the product attribute.

```
$product = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCurrActiveProduct($skuChild); 
$product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```